# Open form using webpart

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010, xmlformview

I'm a problem to open a infopath form using XmlFormView. Here you have the code:

```
   SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
   try
   {
       XmlFormView form = new XmlFormView();
       String templateLib = "FormServerTemplates";
       String xsnName = report + ".xsn";
       form.XsnLocation = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", SPContext.Current.Web.Url, templateLib, xsnName);
       manager.AddWebPart(form, "TopZone", 0);      
    }
```

So I create a page and I add a xmlform webpart to see infopath report in a page. The problem is when I try to open the page:

***A form template (.xsn) file cannot be accessed. You may not have the required permissions to open the file.***

***Correlation ID:51a2dcd8-d2fa-4d8b-ae13-1b5f9caa1c51***

It's weird becouse I can open the same form when I click on the content type that i assigned in a document library, but in a page, it's impossible to see it. What's going on here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, can you check the exception in the SharePoint logs and add it to the post?

They are located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\LOGS. You can use the correlation ID to find the exception.

Additionally, try using elevated privileges like this:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    // your code here
});
```